# Docker container throwing internal node_module error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am trying to setup an environment of three docker containers for a website. One for the frontend, one for the backend and one for the database.

Each one of these has a Dockerfile and I am building them all via the `docker-compose up` statement.

Now the express-backend container always throws following error:

```
songquiz_backend   | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
songquiz_backend   |   throw err;
songquiz_backend   |   ^
songquiz_backend   |
songquiz_backend   | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/app'
songquiz_backend   |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
songquiz_backend   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
songquiz_backend   |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
songquiz_backend   |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
songquiz_backend   |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
songquiz_backend   |   requireStack: []
songquiz_backend   | }
songquiz_backend exited with code 1
```

This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
# Definieren des Basis Docker Images
FROM mongo-express

# Erstellen des Anwendungsverzeichnisses
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Kopieren der Konfigurationsdateien
# package.json und package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Installieren der Abhängigkeiten
RUN npm install

# Kopieren der Quelltextdateien
COPY . .

# Freigeben des Ports, unter dem der 
# Express-Server läuft
EXPOSE 8080

# Starten des definierten npm-Scripts
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
# Alternativ Starten im Debug-Modus
# CMD [ "npm", "start:debug" ]
```

And this is the `server.js`:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

I already tried deleting the node_modules folder in the project folder and reinstalling the modules via npm install.

Comment: What does start:debug look like in package.json?

Comment: I guess you mean the package.json in the project folder. It looks like this:

`{
  "name": "ss2022_wa_songquiz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "start.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node start.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  }
}`